# Image Magick blend 2 cropped/resize images together in the middle

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, alphablending, imagemagick.net

Hey all I have this code below that takes 2 images and merges them together with it fading in the center:

```
convert testingl.jpg -gravity West ^
testingr.jpg -gravity East ^
blend_mask.png -extent 1080x440 -gravity center -composite bothBlended.jpg
```

The above produces this:

[image]

Using this mask:

[image]

Taken from these 2 images (lowered res to fit on here):

**testingl.jpg** (original size 1224 x 1632)

[image]

**testingr.jpg** (original size 828 x 1792)

[image]

This code works great as-is. Does what I need it to do but with one exception - I am wanting to get more of each image into it. Like resize the image, crop from the center the image then take that and blend it. I need to keep the same 1080 x 440 overall size.

Do that with both would look something like this:

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

When running @fmw42's code:

```
convert ^
( testingl.jpg -resize 1080x440^ -gravity West -extent 1080x440 ) ^
( testingr.jpg -resize 1080x440^ -gravity East -extent 1080x440 ) ^
blend_mask.png -composite abc.jpg
```

I get this:

[image]

Comment: You need to escape the ^ on the resize dimension to ^^, as that is an ImageMagick symbol. But the Windows end of line ^ are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ImageMagick command does not generate your proposed output image. I think it is missing a resize and parentheses.

In Unix syntax, I need the following to get your output.

```
convert \
\( testingl.png -resize 1080x440^ -gravity West -extent 1080x440 \) \
\( testingr.png -resize 1080x440^ -gravity East -extent 1080x440 \) \
blend_mask.png -composite bothBlended1.jpg
```

[image]

or perhaps you want

```
convert \
\( testingl.png -resize 1080x440^ -gravity West -extent 1080x440 \) \
\( testingr.png -resize 1080x440! -gravity East -extent 1080x440 \) \
blend_mask.png -composite bothBlended2.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my updated OP. It does not seem to combine them.. only spaces them out?

Comment: See my comment about escaping the ImageMagick ^.

Comment: Ah yes. That did it. Thanks @fmw42!